# Spring Boot PostgreSQL application heroku http 503 H10 error

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, heroku-postgres

I built a spring boot rest service with postgresql database which is working fine locally. I am trying to deploy my project to Heroku. I restored my database to Heroku postgres and did the connection configuration, tested locally, database connection is fine. I deployed it to heroku successfully, but the application is not working.

HTML error:

> GET https://earthinfotr.herokuapp.com/ 503 (Service Unavailable)

> GET https://earthinfotr.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico 503 (Service Unavailable)

Heroku Logs:

> 2022-08-20T21:58:10.213261+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=earthinfotr.herokuapp.com request_id=9531b542-93c4-4ecf-a741-e757409e522e fwd="78.190.148.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

> 2022-08-20T21:58:10.402172+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=earthinfotr.herokuapp.com request_id=338bd6ac-7c14-4827-a928-880db0c12f09 fwd="78.190.148.67" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

The procfile:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/spring-boot-info-earth-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

system.properties:

```
java.runtime.version=17.0.4
PORT=process.env.port || 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the exact solution, but somehow I made it work. The free plan of Heroku postgres allows you to use max 10,000 rows for one database, I had 150k+, the interesting part is heroku is not giving a proper error for that. I deleted lots of data to get it under 10k rows, then I created a new spring boot project, transfered my all code to there and it worked fine.
Here is the application:

https://earthinfo.herokuapp.com/

PS: I deleted only cities(lots of cities), you can test it in Turkey's cities.